# I need to show an alert when i close the window based on condition it will close the current page and go back to previous page

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8

In angular how do give alert when we close the window and in that if user click yes in alert means it go the previous page and clicks cancel means it maintain the same page
I tried this , but i donot know how to give conditions

```
if(window.confirm(`Are you sure')){
Window.alert('closing window')
Window.open('', ''_self')
Window.close()
}
else 
{
alert('canceled')
}
```

But in my case else part is only working and i need to give a condition for both ok and cancel in alert

Comment: The closest you're going to get is [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) (thankfully)